# UnboundLocalError in text-based game

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to make my move in this game, it gives me an UnboundLocalError for a variable. I don't understand why it is happening, can someone explain it to me and tell me how to fix it?

```
pro = '> '
import random
chamber = random.randint(1, 6)
def initialMenu():
    print "Welcome to Russian Roulette!"
    print 'Type "R" for the rules or "P" to play.'
    play_or_rules = raw_input(pro)
    if play_or_rules == 'r' or play_or_rules == 'R':
        rules()
    elif play_or_rules == "P" or play_or_rules == 'p':
        turn()
    else:
        print 'ERROR: Must type in "R" or "P" at the beginning. Restarting program.\n'
        initialMenu()

def rules():
    print "You have a revolver. You and 1 friend play this game. You load 1 bullet into one of the six chambers."
    print "On your turn, you can pull the trigger on yourself, on your opponent and then yourself, or spin the chamber."
    print "You may spin the chamber as much as you like before firing."
    print "Once you fire at yourself, your turn ends, and your friend's begins."
    print "Keep in mind that the game isn't completely random; there can be some strategy to it.\n"
    initialMenu()
def turn():
    print 'Type "Q" to shoot yourself, "W" to shoot your opponent and then yourself, or "E" to spin the chamber.'
    move = raw_input(pro)
    if move == 'q' or move == 'Q':
        if chamber == 1:
            print "BANG! Your brain splatters on the wall. YOU LOSE"
        else:
            print "CLICK! You live another round."
            chamber += 1
            if chamber == 7:
                chamber = 1
                turn()
            else:
                turn()
    elif move == 'W' or move == "w":
        if chamber == 6:
            print "CLICK! Your opponent lives."
            print "BANG! You don't."
            print "YOU LOSE"
            #first shot would be blank, second wouldn't
        elif chamber == 1:
            print "BANG! Your opponent's head has a hole in it."
            print "YOU WIN"
        else:
            print "CLICK! Your opponent lives."
            print "CLICK So do you."
            chamber += 2
            if chamber == 7:
                chamber = 1
                turn()
            elif chamber == 8:
                chamber = 2
                turn()
            else:
                turn()
    elif move == 'e' or move == 'E':
        chamber = random.randint(1, 6)
        print "You spun the chamber, but it is still your turn."
        turn()
initialMenu()
```

Thanks for the help!
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/russianroulette.py", line 62, in <module>
    initialMenu()
  File "C:/Python27/russianroulette.py", line 11, in initialMenu
    turn()
  File "C:/Python27/russianroulette.py", line 61, in turn
    turn()
  File "C:/Python27/russianroulette.py", line 27, in turn
    if chamber == 1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'chamber' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Could you please post the *full* error (with stack trace)? That way people can have an idea where to look.. That being said, `UnboundLocalError` means you're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist. Check for typos.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chamber` is a global variable, and `chamber` inside your function is seen as a *local* variable when python tries to figure out the scope of the variable which results in your `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: Alright, but how do I fix it? If I cut and paste it into turn() it'll redefine every turn, and that isn't what I want.

Comment: `global chamber` at the top of your function and you can leave chamber defined at the top or preferably restructure your code